# Red fox with blue legs

Tags: zoology, mammals, photography, image-processing

On the Wikipedia I found this photo of a red fox, labeled as being taken at Quesnel Lake, British Columbia:

[image: Red fox]

Why would the fox have blue legs? Is that normal for a Red Fox?

Comment: It is black skin and fur. The blue is just a problem with the White Balance of the photograph. Remember the Blue Dress thing on Facebook earlier this year?

Comment: I suppose one could expand on @AMR to make an answer.

Comment: I find it kind of hard to believe the legs appear blue because of "white balance". The nose and upper part of the legs are black, so it is not like all the black in the photo is appearing blue.

Comment: If you look at the top of the nose, it also appears blue. The black parts that are in full light appear blue: it's just a matter of lighting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Original vs. Adjusted**

[image]
[image]

**Adobe Camera Raw Temperature Adjustment +30 / Tint Adjustment +3**

The fox has black skin and fur. The blue is just a problem with the White Balance of the photograph. See Adjustments made above.

This is similar to the Blue Dress / White Dress Meme this year.

> I find it kind of hard to believe the legs appear blue because of "white balance". The nose and upper part of the legs are black, so it is not like all the black in the photo is appearing blue. **– Imprisoned Rhesus**

The reason the legs look Bluer than the Nose is that the nose is mostly black with no white and the front part is in shadow. The top part, which is reflecting some of the sky appears blue in the original.

The reason the legs look more blue is

1. They are not in shadow
2. There is a good amount of white fur mixed in with the black

The white fur will look far bluer when the white balance is off and will trick your eyes into seeing the black as blue.

Comment: Anyone know how to edit to place the photos side-by-side?

Comment: [How to put images side by side](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265996/how-can-i-put-images-side-by-side-in-a-stack-overflow-question). Nice answer btw +1